# Mysql & multi-tenant db: the best way to organize?

Tags: mysql, multi-tenant

I've never completed any multi-tenant project before...

What is the best way to organize multi-tenant db using mysql? and to seperate access between different companies?

sure it can be done in a different ways:

1. different database for each company
2. different tables for each  company
3. one db each table with column tenant_id

i prefer 3rd option.

but: is it possible somehow to limit access between different companies data, for example using mysql schema (or something another) and not using back-end code?

i heard something, that in postgresql its possible using schema...

but is this possible in mysql? (for example tenant1 cannot view data of tenant2)

Answer (score 2):

- If you have thousands of tables or thousands of databases, there could be performance problems.
- If you let customers connect on their own directly to mysql, then *you* must control their `GRANTs`, which can be managed at the database or table level.  (This is one way to 'limit access'.)
- If you throw all customers into the same set of tables, then you must provide security via an application layer, and manage logins yourself, not via MySQL's `GRANTs`.
- You *could* try to use `VIEWs`, with permissions, to constrain users.  Let users connect to the dataset, but limit them to views only.  Build into the views a way to limit them to `tenant_id...`.  (I have not thought through this approach; it may have fatal flaws.)
- A 4th option is to have separate instances of MySQL; each customer has nearly-complete control of his instance.  (You maintain admin control.)
- With the 4th option, there are many choices - VMs, Docker, mysql_multi, etc.  Be warned:  those tend to work better on *nix, not Windows.  (In spite of decades of development, Win still lags behind *nix when it comes to being "ready for prime time" in the 'server' arena.)
- With the 4th option, CGroups could be used to limit each customer's resource usage.  This way one runaway customer cannot significantly hurt the other customers.
- Another consideration:  How easy will it be to "shard"?  That is, have multiple servers, each handling some of your customers.  In particular, what will it take to migrate a customer from one shard to another.  Once you have solved that, you have addressed the questions of how to upgrade the hardware, OS, MySQL version, etc.
- Do you provide specific client software (a la WordPress) (SaaS)?  Or are you simply providing a database engine (DaaS)?
- Will there be client software on the same server?

Comment: A 4th option is to have separate instances of MySQL; each customer has nearly-complete control of his instance. (You maintain admin control.) - it's too expensive... 

simply providing a database engine - this option

Will there be client software on the same server - maybe yes, maybe no (it depends... i could set up it there or not: if there are some issues with db)